# VS 2010 Debugging old build

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I have a visual studio 2010 web project that when I publish it in debug mode the application works fine and is the latest build.

However, when I try to click the play button/debug mode (in the same build configuration as what I published in) the assembly version is older than the most current one. As mentioned, this is a asp.net application using a c# class library as a reference (also in the solution) and I am debugging using Visual Studio's built-in web server.

I've tried everything I could think of at first in all different combinations as follows:

- Clean solution
- Clean each individual project
- Build solution
- Build each individual project
- Rebuild solution
- Rebuild each individual project

I tried to use a different browser and cleaned my cache as well.

Has this happened to anyone? How can I correct this issue?

Comment: How do you determine which version you are debugging?

Comment: I have a version number and build date displayed on the page using reflection... When I publish it's a newer version than what's in the debug version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most likely not set to build. To test this, try build then debug and see if things work. If so, then it is definitely not set to build.

To solve this, open up the Solution Properties. Go to Configuration Properties >> Configuration. Then run down to the project in question and check the Build checkbox. You will then be able to debug again.

This one bit me when a coworker decided the build of the UI was taking too long for his testing and removed it from the build. After discovering the issue, I had him create a separate solution to test in isolation. Yes, multiple solutions can contain the same project(s).

Comment: Thanks, but I said in my OP I'm using the same build configuration

Answer (score 1):

did you try deleting  your bin and obj folders and removing your assemblies from the [GAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Assembly_Cache)? I would guess that THIS is the problem.

Comment: @Muad'Bid: I'll try this, however, if I have to do this every time I debug it isn't much of a solution :(

Comment: yeh, welcome to the wonderfull world of ASP.net  you think that is bad, try sharepoint development. <sigh>

Comment: so i deleted the bin and obj folders and now im getting provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could not be found. 

It still works when I publish it though!

Comment: @Jeffrey Kevin Pry that's bizarre, normally your bin and obj folders only hold the binaries that get regenerated when you build the project. the Clean command in VS deletes the bin but not the obj folders. so its like a more thorough Clean command

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to clean your Temporary ASP.Net (c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework[version]\Temporary ASP.NET Files) files.

After that, do a rebuild and try.

Also, for local development, if you can, then do not GAC assemblies. GAC them while deploying to integration environment. THis will help speed up development a bit.